# How can I configure Angular to serve in dev mode, but using selected production environment variables?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, environment-variables

I'm in the early phases of development in my project and constantly switching back and forth between using a local dev backend service vs using the real production version (in my development angular environment that is).

So I'm basically switching back and forth between commenting lines in my code:

**service.ts**

```
this.http.post(
  'http://127.0.0.1:port/endpoint',
  //'https://production-server.com/endpoint',
  // ...
```

I've just upgraded to using my `environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts` files properly

**environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  backendServiceEndpoint: 'http://127.0.0.1:port/endpoint',
  // bunch of other dev config stuff
};
```

**environment.prod.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  backendServiceEndpoint: 'https://production-server.com/endpoint',
  // bunch of other production config stuff
};
```

So now my code actually looks like:

**service.ts**

```
this.http.post(
  environment.backendServiceEndpoint
  // ...
```

So for the "bunch of other config stuff" this was a really useful change. But I still want to test the production backend while in dev mode with angular. I know I could use `ng serve --prod` to get the `environment.prod` config, but I don't want everything to switch out, just the `backendServiceEndpoint`. What's the best pattern/method for achieving this?

I was thinking that an ideal way would be to have some custom flag I can tack onto the `ng serve` command, but I don't think it's possible for me to make one.

*Added context: This is actually an ionic project. So I'm really using `ionic serve`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options outlined in the [angular build docs](https://angular.io/guide/build)

My recommended approach will be to use the `proxy.conf.json` file to proxy all requests. Which you can alternate by how you call the serve command.

`ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`

An example proxy file:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    },
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

This will rewrite the `api` in the path, but depends on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use `ng serve --configuration=<your env name>` and wire this up in your `angular.json` file under "configurations".

See: https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-target-specific-file-replacements

If your configuration is complex and needs to change based on other variables I would use a configuration "service". I dynamically set/change things for instance with my `HttpClient` usage and what the user is entitled to.

Duplicate of [How to set environment via `ng serve` in Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50174584/how-to-set-environment-via-ng-serve-in-angular-6)

Comment: Thanks. Just as useful as @c_ogoo but gave them the solved check just as this came in.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using the Typescript compiler API to transpile `environment.ts` in memory. I've documented that here, along with an alternative solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63065866/843625